# compliance server error when trying to access stellar.toml file

Tags: compliance

I am testing compliance, bridge and federation servers simulating payments between two FI

One of my compliance servers is displaying the following error when trying to contact the other FI:

**err="lookup federation server failed: get stellar.toml failed: http request failed with non-200 status code"**.

This seems a bit weird, I am able to get stellar.toml file from the other FI when using Postman or the browser. Furthermore, the federation server is also working and CORS is allowed.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. It turned out that the organization from which the tolm file was requested was not redirecting one of their server names correctly. Normally the compliance server will make a http request to the domain name after the * in a federation request. For example, if a federation address is user@email*domain.com and domain.com has server names as www.domain.com and domain.com, the compliance server will be making http requests to domain.com. This was the server name that was not correctly configured.